# Parallel axis in addition to secondary axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I'm trying to plot three differently scaled variables within the same plot. I already used the y-axis and secondary y-axis for presenting two of the three variables. However, I have difficulties to add a axis for the third variable. I'm thinking about a second parallel y-axis. I found one example here but it is not in ggplot:

[image: copyright by R-bloggers]

How can I add a second parallel y-axis in ggplot2?

Comment: Can you share your data and code?

Comment: Posting an example and starting point with code would be a very good idea, but you are hereby warned that within the R user community there is a fairly intense aversion to building such plots. They are seen as potentially misleading or confusing. Stacking separate plots is considered better. (Not trying to start an argument, just trying to give you a heads up.)

Comment: @42 Thank you very much. I followed your suggestion and used facet_wrap to produce three stacked plots. Thanks a lot.